# static NSRegularExpression always nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

```
static NSRegularExpression *isRichContentRegex;
static NSError *regexError = NULL;

@implementation MkContentUtils

+(void)initialize{
if(isRichContentRegex == nil)
{
    isRichContentRegex = [isRichContentRegex initWithPattern:@"<(?!br|p)+[^>]*>"         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
//      isRichContentRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"            (?!br|p)+[^>]*>" 
//                                                                     options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
//                                                                      error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"isrichcontent_pattern:%@",isRichContentRegex.pattern);
}
```

print log is :isrichcontent_pattern:(null)  why the expression is still nil??

Comment: it is easy, because this `<(?!br|p)+[^>]*>` regular expression is invalid, thus you get a `nil` pointer back. you should make a correct regular expression and you will get a valid object back.

Comment: i have fixed it as <(?!/?(br|p|i|b|strong))[^>]*>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never allocate a `NSRegularExpression` object, so you call `init` on `nil` which guaranteed to return `nil`:

```
isRichContentRegex = [isRichContentRegex initWithPattern:@"<(?!br|p)+[^>]*>"         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
```

Change it to:

```
isRichContentRegex = [[NSRegularExpression  alloc] initWithPattern:@"<(?!br|p)+[^>]*>"         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
```

Comment: Thank you ,But it still nil.  I have append the code "if(isRichContentRegex == nil) NSLog(@"still nil");" ,it has printed "still nill" .

Comment: see the comment to your question (by @holex)

Comment: yes, it is `nil`, because the `<(?!br|p)+[^>]*>` regular expression is wrong, so replacing the init method was not the solution to this problem. :(

Comment: @BinyaminSharet, however, **you are also right**, because with any valid pattern the asker needs to replace the init method you've suggested but not this is the only problem here.